# helperText field in TextField are showing 3 dots(ellipsis) while overflow in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using TextField in Flutter. While I am using helperText field to show some information, the text is being clipped with 3 dots at the end. Here is my code:

```
TextField(
     decoration: InputDecoration(
        helperText: 'veryyyyyy longggg text!'
     ),
);
```

Here is how it is happening:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Luckily, I already found solution and just wanted to share with you!

```
TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
         helperText: 'veryyy long text',
         helperMaxLines: 3, // give as many lines as you want not to overflow
         errorText: 'there may also be long error text',
         errorMaxLines: 3, // Solution is very similar   
     
    )
);
```